# Can't insert row into table "attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 sections after the update"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Followed this tutorial, https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/5/overview

I keep getting this error when I insert a row at the top of the table,

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 0 into section 0, but there are only 0 sections after the update'"

Here is the code that handles this.

```
func submit(_ answer: String) {
    let lowerAnswer = answer.lowercased()

    if isPossible(word: lowerAnswer) {
        if isOriginal(word: lowerAnswer) {
            if isReal(word: lowerAnswer) {
                usedwords.insert(answer, at: 0)

                //the below code is for animation even though we just inserted at index 0, the top of the table!

                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)


            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should be allowing me to insert the data from the UIAlertController then populate the tableview at the top.

Below is my ViewController

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    var allwords = [String]()
    var usedwords = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let startWordsURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "start", withExtension: "txt") {
            if let startWords = try? String(contentsOf: startWordsURL) {
                allwords = startWords.components(separatedBy: "\n")
            }
        }
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(promptForAnswer))

        if allwords.isEmpty {
            allwords = ["silkworm"]
            }

        startGame()
    }

    func startGame() {
        title = allwords.randomElement()
        usedwords.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return usedwords.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Word", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = usedwords[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    @objc func promptForAnswer() {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Answer", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addTextField()

        let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default) {
            [weak self, weak ac] action in
            guard let answer = ac?.textFields?[0].text else {return}
            self?.submit(answer)
        }

        ac.addAction(submitAction)
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }

    func submit(_ answer: String) {
        let lowerAnswer = answer.lowercased()

        if isPossible(word: lowerAnswer) {
            if isOriginal(word: lowerAnswer) {
                if isReal(word: lowerAnswer) {
                    usedwords.insert(answer, at: 0)

                    //the below code is for animation even though we just inserted at index 0, the top of the table!

                    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

                    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func isPossible(word: String) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func isOriginal(word: String) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func isReal(word: String) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want help, you need to show your table view data source code.

Comment: @matt I added the rest of my code for context.

Comment: You are returning `usedWords.count` for number of sections. You should return 1 for number of sections and `usedWords.count` for number of rows

Comment: That fixed it thank you @Paulw11 you should leave it as an answer if I can select that as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning `usedWords.count` for the number of sections and you haven't implemented `numberOfRowsInSection`.  This means that you have `usedWords.count` sections in your table, each with 0 rows.

You tell the tableview that you are inserting a row, but `numberOfRowsInSection` is still 0, so you get an exception.

You want a single section with `usedWords.count` rows:

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) {
    return usedWords.count
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the default implementation of `numberOfSections` returns 1 so you don't need to override it if you only want one section.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is in xamarin.ios, you can write it in swift.

1. Update datasource first then
2. Try to add new section zero.

```
var sectionindex = new NSIndexSet(0);
tableView.InsertSections(sectionindex,UITableViewRowAnimation.Bottom);
```